# Outlook Form Region as a new window

Tags: c#, vsto

I am creating a new VSTO add-in for Outlook 2013 & 2016. I have setup a Ribbon (XML) with a button that fires an event, which eventually opens a standard WinForm. The design (Ribbon location, menu, popup window size & location, etc...) is based off the "Signatures" ribbon button under "New Message".

Everything is fine and dandy until I realized that some of the features I want needs Outlook-specific controls. Adding them to my project's toolbox, I found out that they can only work on Outlook Form Regions, and not standard WinForms. I am able to get this to work with the standard FormRegion under the "New Message", but this is not desired behavior. Instead, I would prefer to have it pop up much like the standard "Signature" panel.

I would prefer solutions in C#/VSTO. If a solution would require a third-party alternative to VSTO, I would rather implement this in C++ instead.

Comment: So what's preventing you from implementing your UI in a Windows Form? A specific Outlook control with no WinForms equivalent?

Comment: That's exactly it. I want to use certain controls only available on the Outlook Form Region. Although I can add them to the toolbox, they will not work with standard WinForms and there is no easy way to make then work.

Comment: Which controls specifically?

Comment: **Microsoft Outlook Body Control** and **Microsoft Outlook Recipient Control**

Comment: The Windows Forms WebBrowser control can work as a substitute to handle HTML messages, or the RichText control for the odd RTF email. I've never seen a 3rd party equivalent of the recipient control, but I think I created a similar one once (it's not available for easy consumption, even if I can find it) - it shouldn't be TOO hard